# size argument of plot() functio n in R

Tags: r

i have been searching for a while now but for some reason can't find the argument of the plot() function I can set the x&y dimensions of my plot with.

Does anyone know what i am looking for?

Just for clarification:
this is my plot() function so far:

```
plot(0,0,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0.5,0.5+dim(RT)[1]),axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="")
```

and I would like to have sth of that sort:

```
plot(0,0,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0.5,0.5+dim(RT)[1]),axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="", xsize = 10, ysize = 15)
```

Comment: Are you perhaps using Rmarkdown?

Comment: yes i am . i tried knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=<..>, fig.height=<..>) and that worked. so problem solved but that you anyways very much for your quik response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to set up the plot window first:

```r
X11( height=5, width=10 )
plot( ... )
```

Comment: thank you very much.  i am in rmarkdown and just found knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=<..>, fig.height=<..>),  which works well for me . still thank you very much for the response

Comment: np! should have figured it was for markdown.. poeple are seldom bothered with window dimensions on the desktop anyway, its a simple mouse drag away to fix.